# ubuntu - how do install software as this user, not with sudo. Getting error "Could not open lock file "

Tags: installation, sudo, elasticsearch

I have been told to not use sudo so that the package concerned get installed locally by a regular user.

How do I do that, given that I get the following:

```
apt-get install elasticsearch

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: This probably belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoever told you that this was possible was mistaken. Installing software on Ubuntu (or any Debian derivative) requires root rights. The prepackaged software can only be installed as root.

It may be possible to manually compile and install the software though.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to put yourself in the sudoers list or use sudo.  If you don't have permission, you really don't have any other option

Answer (score 0):

Root privileges are needed for apt-get upgrade too, so:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```